# ImportError: cannot import name 'views' from 'learning_log'

Tags: python, django

I am beginner in django and following a tutorial. got import error even after typing the exact code. here is the code

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/index.html')
```

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from  . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'',include('learning_logs.urls', namespace ='learning_logs')),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    ]
```

app urls:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from learning_log import views
app_name = 'learning_logs'
urlpatterns = [
    #HomePage
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^topics/$',views.topics, name='topics'),
    # Detail page for a single topic
    url(r'^topics/(?P<topic_id>\d+)/$', views.topic, name='topic'),
    url(r'^new_topic/$', views.new_topic, name='new_topic'),
```

error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'views' from 'learning_log' (C:\Users\hhh\PycharmProjects\learning_log\learning_log\learning_log\__init__.py)
```

Comment: You probably skipped through the part where `urls.py` is created for the app. The `urls.py` you shared here belongs to project, and with `include` statement, you must include `urls.py` of your app. Then in the app's `urls.py` you can import views.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening due to that the current folder don't have any `views.py` file.

```
from . import views
```

This means you are looking for `views.py` in current folder which isn't available right now. You can try this:

```
from your_appname import views
```

Comment: @Batoota if that's not what you are looking for, then kindly share your directory screenshots ;)

Answer (score 0):

Got it..it had worked perfectly in the current location but apparently i had created a template directory inside my current project which had shifted the path of views.py. I had to refactor views.py to the directory learning_log and it worked.